# When Company A's headquarters is in California, and is CCPA compliant, can a CA user demand deletion of all personal info?

Tags: privacy, california, ccpa

Company A headquartered in California. Its website has CCPA (California Consumer Privacy Act) complainant page.

Can a user that lives in California demand that Company A delete all of the user's personal information, including the email used to register at the website, the user's age information, and any activity with that account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user can always request that their personal information be deleted.

The business generally has an obligation to delete the data but there are a lot of exceptions to that general rule.  The California government has a FAQ on [common reasons that a CCPA request would be denied](https://oag.ca.gov/privacy/ccpa#heading5d).  That links to sections of the law that list more exceptions [1798.105(d)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=CIV&sectionNum=1798.105.) and [1798.145](https://ttps://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=CIV&sectionNum=1798.145.).

Broadly speaking, the law allows the business to retain the data when it is necessary for the operation of the business or for compliance reasons.  So you can't ask for a bank to forget the information they have on you because the bank is required to retain that information for legal purposes.

Comment: To more more specific, it is online forum.  Can you please @Justin Cave add more detail answer?

Comment: @Maxfield - it is hard to be much more specific.  You can make the request.  The company can then either delete the data or give you a reason they need to retain it.  If there is a dispute, it’s going to be very fact specific.  For example, the company may decline to delete user information if there is concern that posts were libelous and user information might be supenoed.  Without a response from the company, though, it’s hard to be more specific

Comment: Yes. The company doesn't response. So Are there anything that users can do ?

Comment: @Maxfield - That's a different question.  The business has 45 days to respond (90 if they notify you).  If it has been more than 45 days since you sent the request, I'd follow up with the business.